# Selectively remove and delete objects from a NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

Basic question. What is the best way to selectively remove and delete items from a mutable Array in Swift?

There are options that do NOT seem to be suited for this like calling **removeObject** inside a

- for in loop
- enumeration block

and others that appear to work in general like

- **for loop** using an index + calling **removeObjectAtIndex**, even inside the loop
- **for in loop** for populating an *arrayWithItemsToRemove* and then use originalArray.**removeObjectsInArray(arrayWithItemsToRemove)**
- using **.filter** to create a new array seems to be really nice, but I am not quite sure how I feel about replacing the whole original array

Is there a recommended, simple and secure way to remove items from an array? One of those I mentioned or something I am missing?

It would be nice to get different takes (with pros and cons) or preferences on this. I still struggle choosing the right one.

Comment: Are you talking about Swift's Array? or about NSMutableArray?

Comment: A NSMutableArray. Thanks for the comment. I changed the title to clarify that.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to loop and remove elements from a `NSMutableArray` based on a condition, you can loop the array in reverse order (from last index to zero), and remove the objects satisfying the condition.

For example, if you have an array of integers and want to remove the numbers divisible by three, you can  run the loop like this:

```
var array: NSMutableArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for index in stride(from: array.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    if array[index] as Int % 3 == 0 {
        array.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

Looping in reverse order ensures that the index of the array elements still to check doesn't change. In forward mode instead, if you remove for instance the first element, then the element previously at index 1 will change to index 0, and you have to account for that in the code.

Usage of `removeObject` (which doesn't work with the above code) is not recommended in a loop for performance reasons, because its implementation loops through all elements of the array and uses `isEqualTo` to determine whether to remove the object or not. The complexity order raises from O(n) to O(n^2) - in a worst case scenario, where all elements of the array are removed, the array is traversed once in the main loop, and traversed again for each element of the array. So all solution based on enumeration blocks, `for-in`, etc., should be avoided, unless you have a good reason.

`filter` instead is a good alternative, and it's what I'd use because:

- it's concise and clear: 1 line of code as opposed to 5 lines (including closing brackets) of the index based solution
- its performances are comparable to the index based solution - it is a bit slower, but I think not that much

It might not be ideal in all cases though, because, as you said, it generates a new array rather than operating in place.

Comment: And for Swift 2.0 you'll want `array.removeAtIndex(index)`

Answer (score 7):

When working with NSMutableArray you shouldn't remove objects while you are looping along the mutable array itself (unless looping backwards, as pointed out by Antonio's answer).

A common solution is to make an immutable copy of the array, iterate on the copy, and remove objects selectively on the original mutable array by calling "removeObject" or by calling "removeObjectAtIndex", but you will have to calculate the index, since indexes in the original array and the copy will not match because of the removals (you will have to decrement the "removal index" each time an object is removed).

Another solution (better) is to loop the array once, create an NSIndexSet with the indexes of the objects to remove, and then call "removeObjectsAtIndexes:" on the mutable array.

[See documentation on NSMutableArray's "removeObjectsAtIndexes:" in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectsAtIndexes:).

Answer (score 4):

Some of the options:

- For loop over indexes and calling `removeObjectAtIndex`: 1) You will have to deal with the fact that when you remove, the index of the following object will become the current index, so you have to make sure to not increment the index in that case; you can avoid this by iterating backwards. 2) Each call to `removeObjectAtIndex` is O(n) (since it must shift all following elements forwards), so the algorithm is O(n^2).
- For loop to build a set of elements to remove and then calling `removeObjectsInArray`: The first part is O(n). `removeObjectsInArray` uses a hash table to test elements for removal efficiently; hash table access is O(1) on average but O(n) worst-case, so the algorithm is O(n) on average, but O(n^2) worst-case.
- Using `filter` to create a new array: This is O(n). It creates a new array.
- For loop to build an index set of indexes of elements to remove (or with `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`), then remove them using `removeObjectsAtIndexes`: I believe this is O(n). It does not create a new array.
- Use `filterUsingPredicate` using a predicate based on a block of your test: I believe this is also O(n). It does not create a new array.

Comment: That's obj-c methods no? subject is about Swift

Comment: @Vinzius: The referenced methods are methods of `NSMutableArray`. `NSMutableArray` is a class in the Foundation framework, which is in both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Exact, my bad. I was searching for Array methods :-) trying to do swift only.