# How can I conform to the Strideable protocol in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, protocols

I'm trying to remove items from an array inside a For loop. In order to do that, I follow the recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699987/selectively-remove-and-delete-objects-from-a-nsmutablearray-in-swift) to loop backwards like this:

```
for (index, bullet:Bullet) in stride(from: bullets!.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    if(currentTime - bullet.life! > bullet.maxLife){
        bullet.removeFromParent()
        bullets?.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error

```
Type '($T12, Bullet)' does not conform to protocol 'Strideable'
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the class for the bullet. This is a Cocos2D app, hence the CCDrawNode Type.

```
import Foundation

  class Bullet: CCDrawNode {
  var speed:CGPoint?
  var maxSpeed:CGFloat?
  var angle:CGFloat?
  var life:CGFloat?
  var maxLife:CGFloat = 0.5

  init(angle: CGFloat){
    super.init()
    self.drawDot(ccp(0,0), radius: 2, color: CCColor.whiteColor());

    self.contentSize = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
    self.angle = angle
    maxSpeed = 10
    speed = CGPoint(x: maxSpeed! * CGFloat(sin(angle)), y: maxSpeed! * CGFloat(cos(angle)))

  }

  override func update(delta: CCTime) {
    self.position.x += speed!.x
    self.position.y += speed!.y
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code about the `bullets` array? Interested to know its type

Comment: @Antonio just added it

Comment: I was more interested in the type of the `bullets` array... however I presume it's just `[Bullet]`

Comment: @Antonio yup, exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a definition of the protocol: [Stridable](http://swifter.natecook.com/protocol/Strideable/)

You can implement it like this:

```
final class Foo: Strideable {
  var value: Int = 0
  init(_ newValue: Int) { value = newValue }
  func distanceTo(other: Foo) -> Int { return other.value - value }
  func advancedBy(n: Int) -> Self { return self.dynamicType(value + n) }
}

func ==(x: Foo, y: Foo) -> Bool { return x.value == y.value }
func <(x: Foo, y: Foo) -> Bool { return x.value < y.value }

let a = Foo(10)
let b = Foo(20)

for c in stride(from: a, to: b, by: 1) {
  println(c.value)
}
```

You need to provide the functions `distanceTo`, `advancedBy` and the operators `==` and `<`. There is more information about these functions in the documentation I linked.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution using the `filter()` method, avoiding the need for an index
altogether:

```
bullets!.filter { bullet -> Bool in
    if (currentTime - bullet.life! > bullet.maxLife) {
        bullet.removeFromParent()
        return false // remove from array
    } else {
        return true // keep in array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your loop as follows:

```
for index in stride(from: bullets!.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
    let bullet = bullets![index]
```

by moving the `bullet` assignment to a separate statement inside the loop.

Comment: Ok, although it doesn't exactly answer how I can conform to that protocol, it does in fact serve the same purpose. Thanks

Comment: In swift compilation error messages need some interpretation and shouldn't be taken literally. It can be interpreted as "add the missing protocol to the tuple", but I think it just means "I can't figure out how to assign this to that". There are several error messages like that, sometimes making no sense...

Comment: disappointed to see this as the "answer". It doesn't answer the title at all. Maybe rename the question? Luckily, @ColGraff actually answered the question